# \r\n in FileWriter for next line

Tags: java, file-handling

I am writing into a text file and i am using `System.getProperty(line.separator);` to go to next line.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
   fw.write("Correct Fields are:"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"\r\n");
```

`"\n"` was not working before so i searched on the web and found `"\r\n"`.

What is `"\r\n"` ? Is it notepad specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\r is carriage return and 
\n is line feed.

This format is OS specific. For windows/DOS \r\n is required. 
For unix \n will be enough 
and for mac \r is used. (until Mac OS 9).Since Mac OS 10+ , \n is used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that modern Apple computers, using Mac OS X (10+), use linefeed (`\n`).  Older macs, using Mac OS 9 and before, used a carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: oops I did not that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No worries, since your answer is accepted as the correct one you should update it with the correct information!  Press the "edit" button and mention that `\n` is now used by Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of [a "newline"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is handled differently on different systems.

To (over)simplify things:  Windows uses CRLF (`\r\n`), UNIX and most other popular modern systems just use a LF (`\n`).

Conveniently, or annoyingly, depending on your perspective, Java sometimes converts "newlines" (`\n`) into the correct form for the target platform.

Answer (score 1):

"\r\n" is two characters: "Carriage return" and "Line feed" .  In Windows, every new line is "\r\n", while on UNIX systems a new line is just "\n".

Answer (score 1):

The newline sequence is platform dependent. On Windows it is `\r\n`. On most Unix systems it is `\n`. On older versions of Mac, `\r` is used. `\r` is the carriage return (CR) character and `\n` is the line feed (LF) character.

[Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 1):

The line separator is platform-dependent (e.g., `"\n"` on UNIX, `"\r\n"` for Windows).

You can save yourself some trouble if instead of using a `FileWriter` directly you wrap it into a `BufferedWriter` which has a `newLine()` method, or within `PrintWriter` which provides a `println` method that deals with these issues for your behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: What is "\r\n" ? Is it notepad specific?

A: No, "\r\n" ("Carriage return-Line Feed") is DOS/Windows specific.

Most compilers just alias "\n" ("newline") to the appropriate sequence for the current platform.  A DOS/Windows compiler will generate the two characters "\r\n"; a Linux compiler will generate the single character "\n" for the same program.

Java (in the interests of cross-platform compatibility) lets you explicitly state what you want.